# How to use scriptreplay?

Tags: terminal, scripting

I know I can replay terminal actions with:

```
scriptreplay /path/to/$STARTTIME-timing.txt /path/to/$STARTTIME-log.txt
```

But how can I replay the actions from, for example, the 2<sup>nd</sup> to the 3<sup>rd</sup> minute? Does `scriptreplay` only offer a "speed up/slow down" option?

Comment: "*How to use ...*" seems a bit too broad and vague as a title for the question - could you change it perhaps to something like "*Extended playback options for scriptreplay (e.g. playback speed, seek, start, end etc.)?*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a perl version of `scriptreplay` that's in the public domain, provided by Joey Hess: [scriptreplay](http://www.ifokr.org/bri/presentations/tools/scriptreplay).

You can adapt that to add start/end features (the author placed that implementation in the public domain).

Here's a quick and dirty modification of that code that takes two additional parameters - the start time (in seconds from start, default 0), and the end time (optional, runs till the end if not specified). Adapt to suit your needs:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
$|=1;
open (TIMING, shift)
        or die "cannot read timing info: $!";
open (TYPESCRIPT, shift || 'typescript')
        or die "cannot read typescript: $!";
my $divisor=shift || 1;
my $start_sec=shift || 0;
my $end_sec=shift;
# Read starting timestamp line and ignore.
<TYPESCRIPT>;
my $printing = ($start_sec > 0 ? 0 : 1);
my $elapsed = 0;
my $block;
my $oldblock='';
while (<TIMING>) {
        my ($delay, $blocksize)=split ' ', $_, 2;
        if ($printing && ($delay / $divisor > 0.0001)) {
                select(undef, undef, undef, $delay / $divisor - 0.0001);
        }
        read(TYPESCRIPT, $block, $blocksize) or die "read failure: $!";
        print $oldblock if ($printing);

        $elapsed += $delay;
        exit if ((defined $end_sec) && ($elapsed > $end_sec));
        $printing = ($elapsed > $start_sec);

        $oldblock=$block;
}
print $oldblock;
```

Comment: I don't really 100% understand perl..ehh. how can I use this? ex.: I put this perl script to "repl.pl" and then: "perl repl.pl TIMINGFILE TYPESCRIPTFILE STARTTIME ENDTIME"? - sorry for asking this :D

Comment: You forgot the divisor as the third argument (before start time, set to 1 for normal speed), but that's pretty much it.